# Sigmoidal Curve in Geometric Growth

Tags: growth

Here is an excerpt from [my textbook](https://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/kebo115.pdf):

> Let us now see what happens in geometrical
> growth. In most systems, the initial growth is slow
> (lag phase), and it increases rapidly thereafter – at
> an exponential rate (log or exponential phase). Here,
> both the progeny cells following mitotic cell division
> retain the ability to divide and continue to do so.
> However, with limited nutrient supply, the growth
> slows down leading to a stationary phase. If we plot
> the parameter of growth against time, we get a typical
> **sigmoid or S-curve**.

> The exponential growth can be expressed as  $W_1 = W_oe^r{^t}$
>
> > $W_1$ = final size (weight, height, number etc.)
> > $W_0$  = initial size at the beginning of the period
> > $r$ = growth rate
> > $t$ = time of growth
> > $e$ = base of natural logarithms

The first paragraph makes perfect sense to me, but what bothers me is the formula given. When I plot the given equation $W_1 = W_oe^r{^t}$, this is what I get;

[image]

Which is clearly not sigmoidal (s-shaped) as my textbook says.
What I think should be the correct equation is:
$$W_1 = \frac{W_o}{1+e^-{^r{^t}}}$$

When I plot this equation, this is what I get:

[image]

Which is slightly better than the previous plot. Though this formula might also be erroneous as I just made it up from the [general formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) of a sigmoid function $S(x) = \frac {1}{1+e^-{^r{^t}}}$

**Why is there a discrepancy between the in-text statement and the plot of the mentioned formula and is there any better formula to depict this growth?**

Also, I have referred to various sites but could not find any satisfactory answer.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If this statement is true (The exponential growth can be expressed as 1=^^), which seems to be the case, then this is a mathematics question. Probably acceptable on Mathematics.SE. I'd love to help, but I stink at math, and am exceedingly impressed that you even bothered to plot this out. I predict you have a bright future in STEM fields!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a mathematics question. (I did upvote you, though, because wow!)

Comment: It is presented confusingly, but they aren’t giving you the equation for the sigmoidal curve. They are giving you the equation for the exponential phase of the sigmoidal curve (Fig 15.6). See [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_growth) for the sigmoidal (logistic) growth curve equation.

Comment: @canadianer - D'oh! I even stated that, but didn't *see* it.

Comment: I agree with @canadier. The formula given corresponds only to the *exponential phase* of the growth curve, which is also clearly indicated on the corresponding figure 15.6.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Thank you for your comment. Before even posting the question, I knew it was borderline Math-Biology, though I chose to ask here since it was from my Biology textbook  (ps: I'm aspiring to be a doctor, but I'm interested in a whole lot of other things too :)

Comment: @canadianer Yeah, that seems to be it, I think. Maybe the authors thought a sigmoidal function would be too complex for the grade level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discussed this question with my biology teacher and he confirmed that the equation $W_1 = W_oe^r{^t}$ just represents the *exponential phase* of the sigmoidal growth, but not the *entire* growth period. This was also helpfully pointed out in the comments.

Though I did find an article talking about the mathematical functions of sigmoidal growth which includes both the exponential and linear phases of growth.

> Within the life cycle of an organ, a plant or a crop, the total growth duration can be divided into three sub‐phases: an early accelerating phase; a linear phase; and a saturation phase for ripening [(Goudriaan and van Laar, 1994)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4244967/#MCG029C7). Therefore, the growth pattern typically follows a sigmoid curve, and the growth rate a bell‐shaped curve. While the sigmoid pattern can be represented piecewise using an exponential, a linear and a convex equation sequentially [(e.g. Lieth et al., 1996)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4244967/#MCG029C13), a more elegant way is to use a curvilinear equation which gives a gradual transition from one phase to the next. For example, based on principles of light interception and leaf area expansion, [Goudriaan and Monteith (1990)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4244967/#MCG029C6) derived a single equation, the expolinear equation, for both the exponential and linear phases of crop growth:
> $$w=\frac{c_m}{r_m} ln [1+e^{r_m(t-t_o)}] \tag{1}$$
> where $w$ is mass, $t$ is time, to is the moment at which the linear phase effectively begins, $c_m$ and $r_m$ are maximum growth rate in the ‘linear phase’ and maximum relative growth rate (RGR) in the ‘exponential phase’, respectively.
>
> > YIN, XINYOU, GOUDRIAAN, JAN, LANTINGA, EGBERT A., VOS, JAN, and HUUB J. SPIERTZ. "A Flexible Sigmoid Function of Determinate Growth." Annals of Botany 91, no. 3 (2003): 361-371. Accessed February 26, 2023. https://doi.org/10.1093/aob/mcg029.

But, *this* equation too does not achieve the smooth sigmoid curve I wanted to see. With this equation you get a plot like the following:

[image]

The equation I suggested is almost close to an equation mentioned in the paper and is not entirely incorrect. The equation uses the logistics function and gets the smooth sigmoidal curve I was hoping to see on the plot.

> Alternative, but simpler, functions that can produce two smooth transitions in a single formula are the classical growth functions. The first is the well‐known logistic function (Verhulst, 1838):
> $$w = \frac {w_{max}}{1+e^{-k(t-t_m)}} \tag{3}$$
> where $k$ is a constant that determines the curvature of the growth pattern, and $t_m$ is the inflection point at which the growth rate reaches its maximum value. At time $t_m$, the RGR is $\dfrac{k}{2}$. As can be seen from eqn (3), the weight at $t_m$ is half of its maximum value, $w_{max}$.

Now, when I plot equation $(3)$, I get what I was hoping for! The smooth sigmoidal growth curve:
[image]

**NOTE:** All the graphs in this Q&A take the growth to be on the y-axis and the time duration to be on the x-axis. The values on the graphs are completely arbitrary.

**27-02-2023 EDIT:** Added equation which depicts sigmoidal growth.